# .svg image file not working as background image depending on where the file is stored

Tags: html, image, svg

When I take an svg image and host in on amazon cdn, or in local web server of visual studio, it fails to work as a background image. I assume its something in the http headers.

http://jsfiddle.net/LB84y/

```
div{
height:200px;
width:200px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-size:100%; 
 }

   .div1{
    background-image:   url(http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/fonts/symbols/pictonic/svgs/google.svg);
   }

.div2{
    background-image:        url(http://resources.emazetest.com.s3.amazonaws.com/vbwebeditor/images/menu/general/google.svg);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Second server (Amazon server I believe) is just letting download the file and not display it as is.

This means this isnt a problem in your script, it is a problem in their servers they probably have a not-for-web-resources-purposes policy or something and they only allow you to upload things meant to be downloaded. This could be a security thing.

Comment: I use that server for resources all the time. I noticed that it downloads the file instead of displaying it. I don't know why this is

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/fonts/symbols/pictonic/svgs/
The first svg image file is stored in normal folder structure.

http://resources.emazetest.com.s3.amazonaws.com/
Where as the second one resource is in XML format. So this may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was content type. 
By setting it to image/svg+xml, it now works.